# Can't get response from Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'am trying to calculate the BMI with JavaScript (Clienside) and Node.js (Serverside).

If I call the Node URL and pass Parameters I get a response,
but if I call the Node URL with an `xhr` I dont get a `responseText`.

I get statuscode 200 but not the `responseText`.

Where is the problem? Thanks for your help!

Node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.get('/bmi', function(req, res){
    var bmi = req.query.weight / (req.query.height * req.query.height);
    var msg = 'Hallo '+req.query.name+', deine BMI ist ' + bmi;
    res.send(msg);
    console.log(msg);
}).listen(80);
```

Javascript

```
function bmi(){
    var response;
    var name = document.getElementById("name-input").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight-input").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height-input").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        //console.log(xhr.readyState);
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
            response = xhr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("response").innerText = response;
        }
        //console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/bmi?name="+name+"&height="+height+"&weight="+weight, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

This header fixed my Problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure your localhost:80 is not used?
I've tried with 8080 and it works (i edit the js request aswell)

Comment: I tried tons of free Ports. You edit the js request, how ?

Comment: Make sure your variables are set:

`xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/bmi?name="+name+"&height="+height+"&weight="+weight, true);
    xhr.send();`

Comment: I use Comodo Internetsecurity, do i have to make some Firewall options for Node.js maybe ?

Comment: Port 80 should be allowed, is node running on the same computer ?

Comment: Yes same computer, i log the output on the console, but i dont get the rosponseTest

Comment: open this url http://localhost/bmi?name=ayrton&height=180&weight=70, what do you get ?